# Second monitor not detected properly after updating to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchpad, 17.04

Just updated a few days ago and I can't get the second monitor to work properly. It just mirrors the laptop screen with the same dimensions & resolution. Going into System Settings > Displays doesn't show the external screen. Nothing turns up in Additional Drivers.

When I turn on the laptop with the monitor already connected, the monitor displays the boot options with the correct dimensions/resolution; it's only later at the login screen that it stops displaying correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: My touchpad click & two finger scroll don't work on some boots, this is also new with the update. Could these problems suggest a driver issue?

Comment: Are you daisy-chaining the monitors through a display port connection.  If so you may need to change some settings in your monitors themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a **Mirror displays** check-box under **System Setting->Displays**?

If there is, un-check it, and the second monitor should appear in the Displays window.

[image]

Comment: The option is unchecked and greyed out as in your screenshot.